# segmentation error while using return statement returning recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>

float small_array_recursion(const float[],int);

int main(){
    float array[]={-34,-89,3,9.67,45,12};

    int size=6;

    float value=small_array_recursion(array,size);

    printf("%s%.2f","smallest value in the array is ",value);
}

float small_array_recursion(const float array1[],int size){
    int len=size-1;

    static float min=3.36e9;

    if(len==0){
        return array1[0]<min?array1[0]:min;
    }
    else if(array1[len]<min){
        min=array1[len];
        return small_array_recursion(array1,len);
    }
    else
       return small_array_recursion(array1,len);
}
```

Comment: Given `array1[0]>max`, where is `max` defined?  Best to post a [mcve].

Comment: Write floats as floats, like 'float array[]={-34.0, -89.0, 3.0, 9.67, 45.0, 12.0};' (use decimal point)

Comment: Apart from that, the code is (still) rubbish. 'max' is missing as already stated. And I can not (yet) recognize any useful logic in this code.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a recursion problem. Having a hammer does not mean that everything around you is a nail...

Answer (score 1):

1. Write floats as floats, like 'float array[]={-34.0, -89.0, 3.0, 9.67, 45.0, 12.0};' (use decimal point)
2. The code is correct, if you replace variable "max" by "min".
3. For special case 'len==0', the following two lines need to be added

   if(array1[len]<min)
   min=array1[len];

to cover the case, if the first array element is the smallest one.

Then, the full, correct code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

float small_array_recursion(const float[],int);

int main(){
    float array[]={-34., 89.,3.,9.67,45.,12.};

    int size=6;

    float value=small_array_recursion(array,size);

    printf("%s%.2f","smallest value in the array is ",value);
}

float small_array_recursion(const float array1[],int size){
    int len=size-1;

    static float min=3.36e9;

    if(len==0){
        if(array1[len]<min)
        min=array1[len];
        return min;
    }
    else if(array1[len]<min){
        min=array1[len];
        return small_array_recursion(array1,len);
    }
    else
       return small_array_recursion(array1,len);
}
```

Anyway, while the example is working. The return values of the function
don't go anywhere when called from within the function. This is possible,
because variable 'min' was declared as static. It might be a good exercise
to achieve the recursion without variable "min" being static.

Yes, like commented by Fe2O3, this clearly is not a recursion problem,
to find the minimum of an array. I agree. Well, it could be seen as an
exercise where recursion can be applied.

Adapted code with recursion without a static variable "min".

```
#include<stdio.h>

float small_array_recursion(const float[],int,float);

int main(){
    float array[]={34., 89.,993.,9.67,45.,120.};
    int size=6;
    float min=3.36e9;
    float value=small_array_recursion(array,size,min);

    printf("%s%.2f\n","smallest value in the array is ",value);
}

float small_array_recursion(const float array1[], int size, float min){
    
    int len=size-1;
    float localmin;
    
    localmin=min<array1[len] ? min : array1[len];
    
    if(len>0) 
    {
        return small_array_recursion(array1, len, localmin);
    }
    else 
    {
        return localmin;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is an excercise asked to do it by recursion. I understand there are multiple ways to do this. i mistakenly wrote max instead of min. Even if it is done, it still shows segmentation error in VS code editor.

Comment: Then, please also accept the answer (means: vote up = arrow up on the left side of the answer). Or if there is still something else about it, like within VS code editor, let us know.

Comment: i am not eligible to vote up

Comment: Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers which says: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."

Answer (score 0):

This is not well suited to `recursion`. If this were an 'interview question', attempting recursion would be a 'fail'.

And, unless there is a space constraint, `double` is more likely a better size for the floating point values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // use spaces to make your values readable
    double array[] = { -34.0, -89.0, 3.0, 9.67, 45.0, 12.0 };

    int minInd = 0;
    for( int i = 1; i < sizeof array / sizeof array[0]; i++ )
        if( array[ i ] < array[ minInd ] )
            minInd = i;

    printf( "Smallest value in the array is %.2f", array[ minInd ] );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Smallest value in the array is -89.00
```